# Displaying ads on shared WinRT 8.1 page

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1-universal

My universal app (not the new UWP10) has almost all pages shared between Desktop and Phone project. The pages are part of the `.Shared` project; same namespace as the platform-specific projects.

Now, it wouldn't be difficult to just add an `AdControl` control to the page, but I'm not sure how to handle platform-specific aspects of the control, like `AdId`, `Height` or `Width`. As the ads in DevCenter are split into two categories (Tablet & PC/Mobile) I don't know what I should enter as the ID parameter. I'm also not sure how I should handle Width/Height adjustment on specific platforms.

What would be the best solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As the ads in DevCenter are split into two categories (Tablet &
>    PC/Mobile) I don't know what I should enter as the ID parameter.***

In the dashboard,you can create two categories of ads, one for PC/Tablet.The other for Mobile and then replace the unit ID and App ID in your VS project respectively.
[image]

> I'm also not sure how I should handle Width/Height adjustment on specific platforms.***

First please judge whether it is phone or PC platform by using [EasClientDeviceInformation class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.exchangeactivesyncprovisioning.easclientdeviceinformation.aspx),after that you can add Adcontrol programtically in cs code for specific platforms as following:

```
var clientDeviceInformation = new EasClientDeviceInformation();
var operatingSystem = clientDeviceInformation.OperatingSystem;
if (operatingSystem.Equals("WINDOWS"))
{
    //add Adcontrol for Windows
    // Programatically create an ad control. This must be done from the UI thread.
    var adControl = new AdControl();
    // Set the application id and ad unit id
    // The application id and ad unit id can be obtained from Dev Center.
    adControl.ApplicationId = "66ad92bf-3c62-4fa8-ad1c-421a56bf0231";
    adControl.AdUnitId = "309519";

    // Set the dimensions(windows)
    adControl.Width = 160;
    adControl.Height = 600;

    // Add event handlers if you want
    adControl.ErrorOccurred += OnErrorOccurred;
    adControl.AdRefreshed += OnAdRefreshed;
}
else
{
    //add Adcontrol for Windows phone
    var adControl = new AdControl();

    // Set the application id and ad unit id
    // The application id and ad unit id can be obtained from Dev Center.
    // See "Monetize with Ads" at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt170658.aspx
    adControl.ApplicationId = "90b6905b-da20-42fc-bb86-c2b41140fe4e";
    adControl.AdUnitId = "311213";

    // Set the dimensions(windows)
    adControl.Width = 300;
    adControl.Height = 50;

    // Add event handlers if you want
    adControl.ErrorOccurred += OnErrorOccurred;
    adControl.AdRefreshed += OnAdRefreshed;
}
```

For more information please refer to the official sample [Scenario2](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/Advertising/cs/Scenario2_ProgramaticAdControl.xaml.cs):

Besides you need to make sure the width and height here are [supported size](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/supported-ad-sizes-for-banner-ads)